# add profile picture on on pressed flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i created a designed profile page for users i need a help to code a function to let the  users select photo from their device when the click on my add button  and i need to save that image data to my database

i just need to open up gallery and let the user select photo and it should save to my data base when she click on add button

**this is the code of my profile page**

```
class ProfileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> parentScaffoldKey;

  ProfileWidget({Key key, this.parentScaffoldKey}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProfileWidgetState createState() => _ProfileWidgetState();
}

class _ProfileWidgetState extends StateMVC<ProfileWidget> {
  ProfileController _con;

  _ProfileWidgetState() : super(ProfileController()) {
    _con = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _con.scaffoldKey,
body: currentUser.value.apiToken == null
          ? PermissionDeniedWidget()
          : SingleChildScrollView(
//              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ProfileAvatarWidget(user: currentUser.value),
                  
                  ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.shopping_basket,
                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      S.of(context).recent_orders,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ),
                  _con.recentOrders.isEmpty
                      ? EmptyOrdersWidget()
                      : ListView.separated(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: false,
                          itemCount: _con.recentOrders.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var _order = _con.recentOrders.elementAt(index);
                            return OrderItemWidget(expanded: index == 0 ? true : false, order: _order);
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return SizedBox(height: 20);
                          },
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**code of profile avatar widget**

```
class ProfileAvatarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  ProfileAvatarWidget({
    Key key,
    this.user,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 160,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                ),
              ),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(300)),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    height: 135,
                    width: 135,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    imageUrl: user.image?.url,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                      'assets/img/loading.gif',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 135,
                      width: 135,
                    ),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  ),
                ),
```

**Users dart**

```
import '../helpers/custom_trace.dart';
import '../models/media.dart';

enum UserState { available, away, busy }

class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String password;
  String apiToken;
  String deviceToken;
  String phone;
  String address;
  String bio;
  Media image;
```

Comment: Too much of a code, please post minimal reproducible one.

Comment: i updated my question  i added 3 codes in case you need more informartion

Comment: @Salahuddeen what issue you are facing?

Comment: i dont have any issue i just need a funtion code that let user to open gallery and select prfile picture for my application when pressed add button on profile avatar widget